# Splitting single rows data into multiple rows

Tags: r, split, row

I have a set of data with co-authorships of 3k authors. I have columns with **Sender** and **Receiver** (or *Source* and *Target*) and a column with **Journal name** and **Publication year**. If some authors have more than one common article, the results gonna be comma-separated in one row. What I'm looking to do is split these rows into multiple rows. [data.frame - my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Koptyaevas/Co-authorship)

For instance:

```
HALL M,DE JONG GF, "['GRAEFE DR 2008 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'HALL M 2010 SOCIAL SCIENCE RESEARCH']"
```

I need to split the last column like this:

```
HALL M,DE JONG GF, GRAEFE DR 2008 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW
HALL M,DE JONG GF, HALL M 2010 SOCIAL SCIENCE RESEARCH
```

I have heard that I need to write a simple cycle in R, but I have no idea how it supposed to look like.

**EDIT**
dput of my data, first 20 rows:

```
> dput(head(temp,n=20))
structure(list(Source = c("HUMPHREY CR", "HUMPHREY CR", "HUMPHREY CR", 
"SELL RR", "SELL RR", "SELL RR", "GARDNER RW", "GARDNER RW", 
"GARDNER RW", "GARDNER RW", "GARDNER RW", "GARDNER RW", "GARDNER RW", 
"GARDNER RW", "FAWCETT JT", "FAWCETT JT", "FAWCETT JT", "FAWCETT JT", 
"FAWCETT JT", "FAWCETT JT"), Target = c("SELL RR", "GILLASPY RT", 
"KROUT JA", "GILLASPY RT", "KROUT JA", "DEJONG GF", "FAWCETT JT", 
"ARNOLD F", "CARINO BV", "ROOT BD", "DEJONG G", "ABAD RG", "DEJONG GF", 
"BOUVIER LF", "ARNOLD F", "PARK IH", "CARINO BV", "ROOT BD", 
"DEJONG G", "ABAD RG"), Type = c("Undirected", "Undirected", 
"Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", 
"Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", 
"Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected", 
"Undirected", "Undirected", "Undirected"), Id = c(2386L, 2385L, 
2384L, 3635L, 3634L, 3636L, 401L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 403L, 396L, 
400L, 402L, 598L, 602L, 601L, 604L, 605L, 597L), Label = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Weight = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), ayjid = c("['HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY']", 
"['HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY']", "['HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY']", 
"['HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY']", "['HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY']", 
"['SELL RR 1978 JOURNAL OF POPULATION']", "['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT', 'FAWCETT JT 1994 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'GARDNER RW 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'GARDNER RW 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", "['DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'GARDNER RW 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['BOUVIER LF 1986 POPULATION BULLETIN']", "['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'ARNOLD F 1989 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'FAWCETT JT 1987 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW']", 
"['ARNOLD F 1989 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW']", "['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'ARNOLD F 1989 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW']", 
"['DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", "['DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']", 
"['DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW', 'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT']"
)), .Names = c("Source", "Target", "Type", "Id", "Label", "Weight", 
"ayjid"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you dput your data.frame please?

Comment: [My data.frame](https://github.com/Koptyaevas/Co-authorship)

Comment: No. no. no. Put the data.frame in your question - all informations gathered in the same place! Do you ever thought that some people could not have access to your link due to firm firewall? If your data.frame is big, just drop a representative subset!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've edited my question. Actually, my data.frame isn't too big, hopefully, someone will ever open it.)

Comment: same no. no no ;) I mean copy paste the result of your dput here and not on something which can be unacessible!

Comment: Thanks again, I'm really new in it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below:

```
s <- strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]|\\'","",df$ayjid),", ",fixed = TRUE)
res <- data.frame(Id = rep(df$Id, lengths(s)), result = unlist(s))

merge(df,res)
```

Comment: I hope you have come across the `lengths` function in the most recent version of R as a replacement to `sapply(s, length)`. But +1 :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I didn't know about `lenghts` nice one, updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward with `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(as.data.table(temp)[, ayjid := gsub("[][]", "", ayjid)],
       "ayjid", ",", "long")
#          Source      Target       Type   Id Label Weight                                            ayjid
#  1: HUMPHREY CR     SELL RR Undirected 2386    NA      1               'HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY'
#  2: HUMPHREY CR GILLASPY RT Undirected 2385    NA      1               'HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY'
#  3: HUMPHREY CR    KROUT JA Undirected 2384    NA      1               'HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY'
#  4:     SELL RR GILLASPY RT Undirected 3635    NA      1               'HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY'
#  5:     SELL RR    KROUT JA Undirected 3634    NA      1               'HUMPHREY CR 1977 RURAL SOCIOLOGY'
#  6:     SELL RR   DEJONG GF Undirected 3636    NA      1             'SELL RR 1978 JOURNAL OF POPULATION'
#  7:  GARDNER RW  FAWCETT JT Undirected  401    NA      3  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
#  8:  GARDNER RW  FAWCETT JT Undirected  401    NA      3       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
#  9:  GARDNER RW  FAWCETT JT Undirected  401    NA      3     'FAWCETT JT 1994 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 10:  GARDNER RW    ARNOLD F Undirected  397    NA      2  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 11:  GARDNER RW    ARNOLD F Undirected  397    NA      2     'GARDNER RW 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 12:  GARDNER RW   CARINO BV Undirected  398    NA      2  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 13:  GARDNER RW   CARINO BV Undirected  398    NA      2     'GARDNER RW 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 14:  GARDNER RW     ROOT BD Undirected  399    NA      1       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 15:  GARDNER RW    DEJONG G Undirected  403    NA      1       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 16:  GARDNER RW     ABAD RG Undirected  396    NA      2  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 17:  GARDNER RW     ABAD RG Undirected  396    NA      2       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 18:  GARDNER RW   DEJONG GF Undirected  400    NA      2  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 19:  GARDNER RW   DEJONG GF Undirected  400    NA      2     'GARDNER RW 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 20:  GARDNER RW  BOUVIER LF Undirected  402    NA      1            'BOUVIER LF 1986 POPULATION BULLETIN'
# 21:  FAWCETT JT    ARNOLD F Undirected  598    NA      3  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 22:  FAWCETT JT    ARNOLD F Undirected  598    NA      3   'ARNOLD F 1989 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 23:  FAWCETT JT    ARNOLD F Undirected  598    NA      3 'FAWCETT JT 1987 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 24:  FAWCETT JT     PARK IH Undirected  602    NA      1   'ARNOLD F 1989 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 25:  FAWCETT JT   CARINO BV Undirected  601    NA      2  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 26:  FAWCETT JT   CARINO BV Undirected  601    NA      2   'ARNOLD F 1989 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 27:  FAWCETT JT     ROOT BD Undirected  604    NA      1       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 28:  FAWCETT JT    DEJONG G Undirected  605    NA      1       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
# 29:  FAWCETT JT     ABAD RG Undirected  597    NA      2  'DEJONG GF 1983 INTERNATIONAL MIGRATION REVIEW'
# 30:  FAWCETT JT     ABAD RG Undirected  597    NA      2       'DEJONG G 1986 POPULATION AND ENVIRONMENT'
#          Source      Target       Type   Id Label Weight                                            ayjid
```

You can use `ayjid := gsub("[][']", "", ayjid)]` if you also want to get rid of the quotes in the resulting column.